# SurveyMonkey v3 API: What gets put in the contacts/bulk "invalid" collection?

Tags: surveymonkey

What has to be wrong with a contact submitted to the `contacts/bulk` operation (described  [here](https://developer.surveymonkey.com/api/v3/?shell#contacts-bulk)) for it to be put in the `invalids` collection shown in the response?

When I exceed the field lengths cited [here](https://help.surveymonkey.com/articles/en_US/kb/Is-there-a-limit-on-the-number-of-emails-I-can-send), SurveyMonkey just truncates the field and returns it in the `successful` collection.  If I put an invalid character in the email address, it just returns a 500 error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `invalids` key is for invalid emails, basically emails that don't match some email validation regex.

So if you POST something like

```
{
    "contacts": [{
        "first_name": "Test",
        "last_name": "Example",
        "email": "notanemail"
    }]
}
```

That should go into the `invalids` list. If invalid characters are causing a 500, that's something I would report as a bug to SurveyMonkey's API support.

Comment: Hmm... even your example causes a 500 for me.  I'll report this to support.  Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: Okay yes that's definitely a bug, basically all those 500s should go to invalids. Great catch!